# Gradient Descent on a logarithmic decline curve in Python

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, integral, gradient-descent

I wish to run gradient descent on a logarithmic decline curve as represented by:

y = y0 - a * ln(b + x).

My y0 for this example: 800

I was trying to do this using partial derivatives with respect to a and b, but while this apparently minimizes the squared error, it doesn't converge. I know this isn't vectorized, and I might be taking the wrong approach altogether. Am I making any simple mistake, or off on this problem altogether?

```
import numpy as np

# constants my gradient descent model should find:
a = 4
b = 4

# function to fit on!
def function(x, a, b):
    y0 = 800
    return y0 - a * np.log(b + x)

# Generates data
def gen_data(numpoints):
    a = 4
    b = 4
    x = np.array(range(0, numpoints))
    y = function(x, a, b)
    return x, y
x, y = gen_data(600)

def grad_model(x, y, iterations):
    converged = False

    # length of dataset
    m = len(x)

    # guess   a ,  b
    theta = [0.1, 0.1]
    alpha = 0.001

    # initial error
    e = np.sum((np.square(function(x, theta[0], theta[1])) - y))

    for iteration in range(iterations):
        hypothesis = function(x, theta[0], theta[1])
        loss = hypothesis - y

        # compute partial deritaves to find slope to "fall" into
        theta0_grad = (np.mean(np.sum(-np.log(x + y)))) / (m)
        theta1_grad = (np.mean((((np.log(theta[1] + x)) / theta[0]) - (x*(np.log(theta[1] + x)) / theta[0])))) / (2*m)

        theta0 = theta[0] - (alpha * theta0_grad)
        theta1 = theta[1] - (alpha * theta1_grad)

        theta[1] = theta1
        theta[0] = theta0

        new_e = np.sum(np.square((function(x, theta[0], theta[1])) - y))
        if new_e > e:
            print "AHHHH!"
            print "Iteration: "+ str(iteration)
            break
        print theta
    return theta[0], theta[1]
```

Comment: Yea, I am having trouble whenever I get past standard linear gradient descent and don't quite know how to tackle this one.

Comment: Haven't actually read the code, but, what do you mean by it doesn't converge? Is the error getting larger, and thus, it is diverging? Or it is just taking too long to converge? Assuming that you did code the derivatives properly, it might just be that you are choosing the wrong `alpha`, or that the direction of the gradient has the sign flipped (`+` instead of `-`).

Comment: I placed a break in the code if my error ever diverges. I believe the partial derivative for my theta[0] (a) variable is correct, but not my theta[1] (b) variable. It appears to converge correctly but only for theta[0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few bugs in your code.  The line

```
e = np.sum((np.square(function(x, theta[0], theta[1])) - y))
```

is incorrect and should be replaced with

```
e = np.sum((np.square(function(x, theta[0], theta[1]) - y)))
```

The formula for new_e contains the same error.

Also, the gradient formulas are wrong.  Your loss function is
$L(a,b) = \sum_{i=1}^N y_0 - a \log(b + x_i)$,
so you have to compute the partial derivatives of $L$ with respect to $a$ and $b$.  (Does LaTeX really not work on stackoverflow?)  A final point is that the gradient descent method has a step size restriction, so our step size must not be too large.  Here is a version of your code that is working better:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# constants my gradient descent model should find:
a = 4.0
b = 4.0
y0 = 800.0

# function to fit on!
def function(x, a, b):
    # y0 = 800
    return y0 - a * np.log(b + x)

# Generates data
def gen_data(numpoints):
    # a = 4
    # b = 4
    x = np.array(range(0, numpoints))
    y = function(x, a, b)
    return x, y
x, y = gen_data(600)

def grad_model(x, y, iterations):
    converged = False

    # length of dataset
    m = len(x)

    # guess   a ,  b
    theta = [0.1, 0.1]
    alpha = 0.00001

    # initial error
    # e = np.sum((np.square(function(x, theta[0], theta[1])) - y))    #  This was a bug
    e = np.sum((np.square(function(x, theta[0], theta[1]) - y)))

    costs = np.zeros(iterations)

    for iteration in range(iterations):
        hypothesis = function(x, theta[0], theta[1])
        loss = hypothesis - y

        # compute partial deritaves to find slope to "fall" into
        # theta0_grad = (np.mean(np.sum(-np.log(x + y)))) / (m)
        # theta1_grad = (np.mean((((np.log(theta[1] + x)) / theta[0]) - (x*(np.log(theta[1] + x)) / theta[0])))) / (2*m)
        theta0_grad = 2*np.sum((y0 - theta[0]*np.log(theta[1] + x) - y)*(-np.log(theta[1] + x)))
        theta1_grad = 2*np.sum((y0 - theta[0]*np.log(theta[1] + x) - y)*(-theta[0]/(b + x)))

        theta0 = theta[0] - (alpha * theta0_grad)
        theta1 = theta[1] - (alpha * theta1_grad)

        theta[1] = theta1
        theta[0] = theta0

        # new_e = np.sum(np.square((function(x, theta[0], theta[1])) - y)) # This was a bug
        new_e = np.sum(np.square((function(x, theta[0], theta[1]) - y)))
        costs[iteration] = new_e
        if new_e > e:
            print "AHHHH!"
            print "Iteration: "+ str(iteration)
            # break
        print theta
    return theta[0], theta[1], costs

(theta0,theta1,costs) = grad_model(x,y,100000)
plt.semilogy(costs)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Works like a charm! Any standard procedure to follow on how to find a correct step size?

Comment: @ScottRothbarth, a few years late, but using a step size smaller than 1/ the lipschitz constant of the objective should work